# QGIS 3.10 Layout Manager not printing Google Satellite background

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer

I am trying to compose a layout with Google Satellite as background. I am trying to add such background both with XYZ tiles utility and with QuickMap Services plugin. In both cases the layer is visible on the map and in the layout, but if a save the layout as Image or pdf, I don't see Google Satellite. I see only a white backgound.

How can the issue be solved?

Comment: Hello, any answer?

Comment: Good day giulio. I am using QGIS 3.20 and regularly see this message if the area of my layout is at a very high scale: >"Some WMS servers (e.g. UMN mapserver) have a limit for the WIDTH and HEIGHT parameter. Printing layers from such servers may exceed this limit. If this is the case, the WMS layer will not be printed"
Not sure if this might be the issue you are facing and that the message simply isn't appearing...